# Can't compile with junit

Tags: java, testing, ant, junit, javac

This is a seemingly easy exercise that I can't get to work. Ultimately, I need to get junit running with ant, but for now I'm just trying to compile a very basic junit test from the terminal (OSX 10.10.5) using javac (I've gotten this exercise to work in eclipse; I'm aware that you have to install junit differently depending on if you're gonna use it in Eclipse or the terminal, and I think that I did that correctly, but probably not).

[Here's](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm) a link to the example. I'm running Java version 1.8.0_25

I downloaded the two .jar files for junit and placed them in the classpath, but I'm getting multiple compiler errors related to not being able to find org.junit...

```
TestJunit.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
...
TestRunner.java:1: error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
```

The java files from the example (TestJunit.java and TestRunner.java) are in `~/JUNIT_WORKSPACE.`

This may be TMI, but here is the entirety of my ~/.bash_profile. I have a feeling that this is where I'm messing up.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home"
export JUNIT_HOME="/usr/local/junit"
export ANT_HOME="~/apache-ant-1.9.6/"
export PATH="$PATH:$JUNIT_HOME"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME/junit4.12.jar"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
alias l='ls -FAlh'
```

I have restarted the terminal (and/or entered `source ~/.bash_profile`) and still can't get this to work. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you check that `junit4.12.jar` is really located in `/usr/local/junit/` ?
You could also try to compile it by providing the classpath explicitly: `javac -cp $PATHTOJUNIT/junit4.12.jar TestJunit.java`.

Btw the default name of the junit jar is `junit-4.12.jar` . You might be missing a dash in your export CLASSPATH stament.

Comment: The dash! Oh God, that dash, that was it. I feel like a jackass. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey it's all cool! Have fun!